# Prevent Ag-Grid from Re-Rendering when Data (NgRx Store) changes

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using Ag-grid and a NgRx Store as its Data Source. The Data is handled in my Parent Component and passed via observable (`tableData`) to my table component.

```
<div class="table-wrapper" *ngIf=tableData>
 <ag-grid-angular
    class="ag-theme-balham"
    [columnDefs]="tableData.columnDefs"
    [rowData]="tableData.rowData" 
    [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
    [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
    (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
    (rowDataChanged)="onRowDataChanged($event)"
    (cellClicked)="cellClicked($)"
    >
 </ag-grid-angular>
</div>
```

The ag-grid columns contain checkboxes. When the user clicks on a cell an Event is emittet which changes the current State of the App, the clicked checkbox and the whole `tableData`. 
As a result the UI reflects those changes as intended.

[image: Table with checkboxes]

```
 @Input tableData;
 @Output cellValueChanged = new EventEmitter<>();

 constructor() { }

 onGridReady(params: any) {
  this.gridApi = params.api;
  this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;

  setTimeout(() => {
   this.gridApi.sizeColumnsToFit();
   }, 1000);
 }

 cellClicked(event) {
  ...
  this.cellValueChanged.emit({ data });
 }
```

The problem with that solution is that the whole table data gets reloaded. This causes the table to resize to autoColumnWidth and also, if I had been scrolling down the table, a reset of the scrollbar to the top state.

Using

```
cellClicked(event) {
  ...
  this.gridApi.updateRowData({ update: data });
}
```

works like a charm, but only if I do NOT update the app state. The problem is that I want and need to update the app state everytime the user performs an action on the table to keep the frontend- and store-data consistent.

How do I prevent the table from rerendering after updating the AppState?

Comment: You should use "deltaRowDataMode" in ag-grid for immutable store. See more details - https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/#example-immutable-store

Comment: Well I tried that without success, but thanks to you pointing me in the direction again i found out that I had to set the ID properly and now it works! Thanks alot!

One Problem still remains:
On cellClicked(), or `api.setRowData(store)` the table resizes to its original form as if I did not set `this.gridApi.sizeColumnsToFit()` before.

Comment: Yes, a unique id needed for each row. I am using this delta mode and it works like a charm. What problem still remains?

Comment: I accidentally sent the Comment prematurely. See the Edit above.

Comment: Well, it should not happen if you have called sizeColumnsToFit once. delta changes do only the data change on the row. in my case, i need to preserve the column width but it does not get change when the delta change happens. Is it possible to create a plunkr or stackbltiz which demo the issue. I will have a look.

Comment: I cannot provide you with a working plunker because it doesnt work from office Lan properly, I will fix it at home. For now here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sc59sf
The table resizes as intended on the first call, but whenever the tableData changes it switches back to its default position.

Thank you alot :) You already helped me tremendously!

Comment: I did try your stackblitz and as you mentioned, it is not working. Once you fix it from home, drop a message, I will look into it.

Comment: Reset to scrollbar can be suppressed by setting "suppressScrollOnNewData = true" in grid options.

Comment: @Amir. Thank you but since using deltaRowMode this is not an issue anymore.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-angular?file=app%2Fmy-grid-application%2Fmy-grid-application.component.ts

Here is a plunker of a similar version not using NGRX Store. I use setRowData but it is working as it should.

Comment: The bug still exists and i have no clue how to solve it. I couldnt post it on stackblitz so i put it on github. i would really appreciate the help. I tried everything but propably my understadning of angular isnt enough for that problem.

 https://github.com/peemoRoyal/ngrx-aggrid-bug

Comment: Also I noticed that the sorting gets reset after the data is updated. It seems like the table is set to a default state, except the scrollbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to your help I found the solution.

First step with NGRX or RxJS is to use deltaRowMode.

Second issue with my code was that I am creating the columnRefs dynamically. When I click on a cell not only the rowData but also the columnRefs would be recalculated. This would lead to the reset of the grid.

Thanks for your help! I learned alot